# Are data models - ILP32 or LP64 decided by OS or the Hardware Architecture?

Tags: c, types, compiler-construction

I am reading through fixed-size data types in C - `(u)intN_t`.

And I understood that using these data types would ensure the programmer that exactly those many number of bits are assured for that data type.

I got curious to understand how this is enforced internally, after bit of research I understood that through the header file, they will be defined like -

```
typedef char int8_t;
typedef short int16_t;
```

And I understood that these typedef are defined in `<stdint.h>` based on the `data model` type being followed by the **platform**. ie whether -

1. ILP32 or
2. LP64 or
3. ILP64 or
4. LL64 etc

So if the platform is following `ILP32` data model, then `int64_t` would be defined like -

```
typedef long long int64_t;
```

If in case, the platform is following `LP64` data model, then `int64_t` would be defined like -

```
typedef long int64_t;
```

But what I couldn't understand is what is a **platform** here?

Does **platform** refer to a *Hardware Architecture* type - x86, x86_64 or AMD etc

or does it refer to an *Operating System* like - Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, Linux, macOS, BSD, or IBM z/OS etc

Is `data model` type decided by an *OS* or by the *Hardware Architecture*?

Answer (score 1):

> Does platform refer to a Hardware Architecture type - x86, x86_64 or AMD etc

Yes

> or does it refer to an Operating System like - Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, Linux, macOS, BSD, or IBM z/OS etc

And yes!

For example ILP32 and LP64 mean that in the former ints, longs and pointers are 32 bits; and in the latter longs and pointers are 64 bit.

While you can use 64-bit pointers for 32-bit memory space, it would be just stupid, because each pointer would consume 64 bits, but you would only *really* use half of that. Just like you'd **always** only print on the left/top half of each sheet of paper. But the processor support is not enough, because the *operating system* has to support that too. x86 processors support many operating modes from 16-bit real mode all the way to 64-bit long mode - one set of hardware, several platform options. You can run 32-bit operating system on your 64-bit processor. And you can run 32-bit programs inside 64-bit operating system on a 64-bit processor!

When I run programs in Linux on my computer they're ILP32 and LP64. When I boot to Windows, the programs there follow the ILP32 and **LLP64** models... So even on the same set of hardware I can have two operating systems and inside them two "platforms" to choose from. And within Linux realm the userland library selections also matter in C development, so the those two common Linux platforms would be called **x86_64-pc-linux-gnu** and **i386-pc-linux-gnu**.

Comment: &quot;When I run programs in Linux on my computer they&#39;re ILP32 and LP64.&quot; - Did you mean a program under Linux can run either in ILP32 or LLP64? And when you say inside an operating system two platforms - Did you mean two different instances of operating system one operating in 32bit mode and another instance operating in 64 bit mode?

Comment: On an standard amd64 hardware: 32-bit Windows appl: `ILP32LL64`; 32-bit Linux appl: `ILP32LL64` (the same); 64-bit Windows appl: `IL32LLP64`, 64-bit Linux-appl: `I32LP64`

Comment: No, 64 bit Intel Linux operating system is (possibly) capable of running both 32 bit ILP32 and 64 bit LP64 programs simultaneously

Comment: So what I can infer from this is - `user programs` (executable) are the ones which follow a particular `data model` type. And compiler is the one which enforces which data model that a particular executable (`user program`) follow. And the `operating system (executable)` will also be following a particular data model. And the decision of what `data model` does the `OS` follows is **somewhat** influenced by the `hardware architecture` on which the `OS `is running. When I say **somewhat** - `OS` has to use 32 variant data model and cant use 64 bit variant data model on a 32-bit hardware. _cont-_

Comment: _cont-..._ However OS can make choice between whether to follow ILP32 or LP32 on a 32-bit machine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, but LP32 would mean that int would not be 32 bit, i.e. it would be 16 bit, such would not make sense on i386, because 16 bit opcodes are longer and slightly slower in 32 bit mode than 32 bit!